# Protected cast not working after using getAttribute (laravel)

Tags: laravel

Here is how defined inside th model. The total does not return in array form after getTotalAttribute is used

```
protected $casts = [
    'total' => 'array'
];

public function getTotalAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->_auth($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure “total” in database is a valid JSON format.

> The array cast is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON.

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting